# How to fix unchanged URLs in Database after running serialized search and replace script?

Tags: database, urls, migration, customization

I just did my first migration from a dev site to a prod site, using the InterconnectIt serialized search and replace script.  The migration worked, but here is where I’m struggling: The site was unusually slow and some clients could not view the slider and images, so we looked through the theme settings and found many URLS still with the dev site address. We had used the back button on the InterconnectIt script and run it several times at the time of migration, and I ran it again several times since then, even changing the GUID columns, but that still didn’t change all of them.

Here are some examples of the old URL left in the options table:

1:  http:\/\/www.example.com\/client\/wp-content

2:  newsletter@example.com

And from the SlimStats plugin table:

3:  www.example.com (with the "http://" in front)

Our criteria was:

Search:  http://www.example.tk/client

Replace:  http://www.client.org

I don't feel competent to use other criteria than that, as I'm not sure of the consequences.  Do I need to search with other variations of the URL in various instances (e.g., without the "http://", without the "www") in order to catch them all?

I've researched and can't find a solution.  Search and Replace Regex plugin only seems to change posts and author stuff, not the other tables.  Other plugins don't seem to be serialized.  I'm hesitant to do it myself in a text editor (as the WPTuts+ migration tutorial showed), as I'm not sure where all the serialized data is.

Have you any clue why some URLs were left unchanged, or if there is something I might be doing wrong? Any help is certainly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Related: https://interconnectit.com/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Answer (score 1):

The better place to put in a bug report is at the github repository for the project: https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB/issues

Comment: Actually I'm looking for help to solve my problem with the URLs still unchanged, either by finding out what I did wrong with the script, or by some other method dealing with serialized search and replace.  I'm not sure it's a bug.  But thank you for the tip.